# Changing status code of invalid URLs hosted in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, http-status-codes, error-code

I'm hosting a static site in AWS S3. I have put a error document in the bucket settings in case the user requests for a object that is not present in S3. I get the error document in such cases, but the status code is still a error code. How can I change it to 200?

Comment: you don't want a 200, how else will "non humans" like Google bot know they are looking at an error page?

Comment: yes. you are correct. the problem for me is that for SEO, the bucket returns 403 instead of 404. I solved it by setting CloudFront in front of the s3 bucket and configuring it to change the status code from 403 to 404.